# Initializing a base class that has the same name as a member variable

Tags: c++

Given that I have:

- a base class called `A`
- a constructor for `A` that takes an `int` argument
- a subclass called `B` that inherits from `A`
- a member variable of class `B` that is an `int` and is called `A`

How do I call the constructor `A::A(int)` in `B`'s constructor? It seems that all I can do is initialize the member variable called `A`.

Her's a short code reproducing the issue:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A();
    A(int);
};

class B : public A 
{
public:
    B();
    int A = 100;
};

A::A()
{
    std::cout << "in constructor A";
}

A::A(int s)
{
    std::cout << "value in A constructor " << s;
}

// Here I want to initialize the base class with 50
// and the member with 78. Is it possible?

B::B() : A(50), A(78) 
{
    std::cout << "in Constructor B";
    std::cout << A;
}

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

I want to initialize class member A with 78, and call the base class constructor with 50. How can I do that?

If I try to assign to the member instead:

```
B::B() : A(50)
{
    A = 78;
    std::cout << "in Constructor B";
    std::cout << A;
}
```

the output is

```
in constructor Ain Constructor B78
```

It's not calling the `A::A(int)` overloaded constructor.

Comment: If still not getting your required result then you must explain it.

Comment: This would be an interesting question if you took the time to actually make it presentable.

Comment: @storyTeller plz check I have edited

Comment: Try this: `B() : A(78), A::A(50) {}`

Comment: @Quentin constructor call order does not depend on the initialiser list order.

Comment: @n.m. wat. Of course I didn't expect the call order to be affected, but I thought it wouldn't compile at all. My bad.

Comment: @Quentin it's a mystery why it ever works, but it does.

Comment: Alright, I tried to sort out your post into something readable. I also undid my down-vote due to the poor quality, and am voting to reopen. In the future though, strive to make your post clear from the start.

Comment: @n.m thank you it worked now as expected

Comment: code :B::B():A(78),A::A(100){
 //A=78;


 cout<<"in Constructior B";
 cout<<A;
} o/p:value in A constructor100in Constructior B78